# GitHub rejected push to master

Tags: github, egit

I tried to push my project into the GitHub by using EGit and I got a confirmation message that it has been pushed but I could not see that file on my GitHub page.

[image]

I don't know about GitHub briefly and I am a fresher to GitHub. Therefore please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: I'm not a github expert, but can see the word "rejected" in the message. Could indicate that it *didn't* work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38737431/6309

Answer (score 0):

From the language used in the error message, I'd say you likely have changes in your remote (on GitHub's copy of master) that aren't in your local master. The fix would be to fetch the remote and merge its changes into your local. You can read more about how to do that at [Dealing with non-fast-forward errors](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-non-fast-forward-errors/).